# Inability to reverse axes in a netcdf file

Tags: r, netcdf, qgis, nco

I really hope someone can help me.
I am working on a NetCDF file and I manage to extract the weighted average along the depth dimension. The next step is to arrange the file in an ASCII file. However, when I upload it on QGIS, it appears clockwise and inversed (find below the picture).
[image: R output]
I've found out that if I upload the NetCDF as a mesh file in QGIS, it appears reversed as in the picture. [image: Mesh on QGIS]

To solve the issue, I've tried to use NCO to reverse the X and Y axis by applying the command ncpdq but it doesn't work. I tried the following:

```
ncpdq --rdr=lat,lon incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
ncpdq -a -lat, -lon, time, depth, -lev incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
ncpdq -O -a -lon incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
```

but no one works. The NetCDF appears always reversed when uploaded in QGIS.
Can you please help me in understanding how to transpose/reverse/flip the coordinates? I've already succeeded in clockwise the R output.
An example of the NetCDF I am using is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq7k8o6zjhp6nid/1999.nc?dl=0)

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Is this relevant at all to your problem? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272184/netcdf-layer-nc-appears-flipped-and-rotated-in-qgis

Comment: Do you need to rotate it or regrid it? If it isn’t latlon then you probably want to regrid

Comment: @Anonymouscoward I've already tried your solution but didn't work

Comment: @RobertWilson I want to rotate it (or better, transpose). The NetCDF is lat lon. I didn't try to regrid

Comment: I've plotted the file you've linked to and it seems fine, and the grid description is correct. Is the file at the dropbox link the incorrect one?

Comment: @RobertWilson, yes it is. Do you plot it as a mesh?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things to try:

If the file is already lat,lon order then the transpose would be lon,lat:

```
ncpdq --rdr=lon,lat incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
```

Eliminate the spaces and quote the arguments:

```
ncpdq -a '-lat,-lon,time,depth,-lev' incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
```

Reverse and transpose:

```
ncpdq -O -a '-lon,-lat' incorrect_file.nc correct.nc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however the hints you suggest don't work